# Class groups of function fields of Riemann surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface, and $f: X \to \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ be a holomorphic branched cover. This induces a finite extension of their fields of meromorphic functions $f^*: \mathbb{C}(z) \to \mathcal{M}(X)$. $\mathbb{C}(z)$ is the field of fractions of $\mathbb{C}[z]$, which is a principal ideal domain, and therefore a Dedekind domain. The integral closure $\mathcal{O}$ of $\mathbb{C}[z]$ in $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is also a Dedekind domain. I believe one can show that $\mathcal{O} = \{g \in \mathcal{M}(X): g^{-1}(\infty) \subseteq f^{-1}(\infty)\}$, so it consists of the functions which are finite everywhere the cover $f$ is finite.

What can we say about the class group of $\mathcal{O}$? Is it related to the Picard group of $X$? As I understand, there is a distinction between the two, in that the prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}$ should correspond to points in $f^{-1}(\mathbb{P}^1 - \infty)$. So the ideal structure of $\mathcal{O}$ does not "see" the fiber of $f$ over $\infty$, whereas the Picard group accounts for arbitrary divisors on $X$. Different choices of $f$ will gives us different integral closures of $\mathbb{C}[z]$ in $\mathcal{M}(X)$. Are there any properties which are invariant under choice of cover?

See Forster, Lectures on Riemann Surfaces, chapter 8 for the algebraic properties of branched covers of Riemann surfaces.

Comment: What is the kernel of $Pic(X)\to Cl(\mathcal{O})$ ? With Riemann Roch you can construct some $f$ such that $f^{-1}(\infty)$ is any non-empty finite set of points.

Comment: @reuns what is the morphism you’re asking about?

Comment: What is your guess?

Comment: The Picard group of Spec $\mathcal{O}$ is the class group of $\mathcal{O}$, so I assume it’s induced by inclusion in X

Comment: The map $Div(X)\to Pic(X)\to Cl(\mathcal{O})$ sends divisors supported on $f^{-1}(\infty)$ to $(1)$ and divisors supported on $X-f^{-1}(\infty)$ to the product of corresponding maximal ideals of $\mathcal{O}$. The kernel is the image of $Div(f^{-1}(\infty))$ in $Pic(X)$.

Comment: Right, for some reason I was thinking of the class group as only accounting for ideals of $\mathcal{O}$, while it actually is defined in terms of all fractional ideals of $\mathcal{M}(X)$. So there is indeed an obvious morphism from Pic($X$) to the class group, as every meromorphic function on $X$ is meromorphic when restricted to an open subset.

Comment: Nevertheless I still wonder if this perspective can shed any light on the Picard group of $X$, by looking at it somewhat more in the vein of algebraic number theory.